# Is ignoring Dockerfile in '.dockerignore' not allowed?

Tags: java, docker, jenkins, dockerfile

(Note: this seems irrelevant to Jenkins but tagging it just incase)

I'm using the Jenkins Docker plugin to build my docker images however my build fails with the following exception: `Dockerfile is excluded by pattern 'Dockerfile' in .dockerignore file`

```
com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.DockerClientException: Dockerfile is excluded by pattern 'Dockerfile' in .dockerignore file
   at com.github.dockerjava.core.dockerfile.Dockerfile$ScannedResult.<init>(Dockerfile.java:184)
   at com.github.dockerjava.core.dockerfile.Dockerfile.parse(Dockerfile.java:111)
   at ...
```

Looks like its using the [docker-java](https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java) library

Upon inspecting the source code, it appears that an exception is thrown if the Dockerfile is ignored here: [Dockerfile.java:L185](https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/dockerjava/core/dockerfile/Dockerfile.java#L185)

So is ignoring the Dockerfile not allowed? And why?

Comment: What OS are you running on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignoring the Dockerfile is supported, though it hasn't always been. From the [current documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file):

> You can even use the .dockerignore file to exclude the Dockerfile and
>   .dockerignore files. These files are still sent to the daemon because
>   it needs them to do its job. But the ADD and COPY instructions do not
>   copy them to the image.

Support for this was added way back in [1.5.0](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/blob/17.06/CHANGELOG.md#150-2015-02-10) (released 2015-02-10):

> Dockerfile and .dockerignore files can be themselves excluded as part
>   of the .dockerignore file, thus preventing modifications to these
>   files invalidating ADD or COPY instructions cache

Answer (score 0):

Excluding `Dockerfile` from `.dockerignore` is supported by docker but it is a bug in `docker-java` library, see issue: https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java/issues/1141